# Deleted comment

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-comments

My comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51177396/6834680) was deleted, and I don't know why.

> Intercept (using metatable(_G)) access to `pre_models()` and run this script. Print serialized `m` on every invocation of intercepted `pre_models()`.

The comment was pretty useful, it didn't violate any rules.

Could admins please determine the user perpetrated such vandalism? What was the reason for the deletion?

---

**UPDATE:**
It appeared that my comment was deleted again.
What was the reason this time?
I guess this time it was not "fat fingers".
Does this site have some sort of anti-vandal mechanism (for example, revoking moderator privileges)?

Comment: I've edited the comment into the question otherwise there isn't a proper context. It was flagged as "no longer needed", and might have been accidentally removed/fat fingered by the mod as the delete link is positioned *very* closely next to the dismiss link in the mod interface.

Comment: You'd have to wonder a bit what could go wrong when they profess to be able to auto-detect snarky comments.  I smell a pr0blem.  @Samuel - sounds like a good cue to undelete that comment.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting the comment.

Comment: Are you aware another user has posted your comment (almost verbatim) as [an answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51200246/1364007)?

Comment: Calling a comment deletion "vandalism" is a bit strong, considering that we're told to treat comments as ephemeral and expect them to be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: @abarnert - No, comments are not "ephemeral", there are a lot of useful comments on SO, it would be silly to delete them.  Yes, I consider deleting useful comments as vandalism unless there is a sane reason for deletion.

Comment: Straight out ot [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), first sentence: “Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.” The help also uses the words “transient”, “disposable, and “ephemeral” along with that “temporary”.

Comment: Likewise, [MSE says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) “You should not expect them to be around forever: Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion. In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.” You may not like that policy, but you won’t get anywhere by pretending it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @abarnert - That's correct.  `the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion` If, for example, an answer would be given based on my comment, then my comment would not be needed anymore, and should be deleted to avoid duplication.

Comment: It seems to be the exact situation here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370541/deleted-comment#comment606328_370541

Comment: Picking and choosing one branch of an “or” doesn’t change the facts. The help says that comments are temporary, and that you should not expect them to be around forever, and that they may be deleted for a number of reasons. Calling it “vandalism” when the site works the way it’s supposed to—and then demanding that someone lose their moderator privileges over it—isn’t helpful.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah well then the help is wrong. Ever consider that bub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I agree with [Nicol Bolas's sentiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370608/908494) that answer-comments are in general not good for Stack Overflow, things are not always ideal, and sometimes, a comment is better than the nothing we'd otherwise have.<sup>1</sup>

But any time you think that a comment's deletion would be so detrimental to the site that it would be "vandalism", that's a sure sign that *the information doesn't belong in a comment*. It belongs somewhere that can be indexed by search engines, seen by people in queues and search results, updated for future changes, linked to and attributed, etc.

[As the SO help says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes** left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

[As MSE says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work):

> **You should not expect them to be around forever**: Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion. In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.

Of course you're free to disagree with some of the site's/community's standards, but that doesn't mean you can demand that a moderator be punished for doing their job according to those standards.

---

<sub>1. Examples: I have an idea for a solution, but I'm too busy or too lazy or too out of my area of expertise to turn it into an answer. I've written an answer or found a dup, and I have some additional info that seems unlikely to be of any value to anyone searching on the same problem later, but that may resolve the OP's unique confusion. I'm afraid that maybe this isn't really a question, but the first round of a help vampire's attempt to use Stack Overflow for an iterative debugging session. I don't want to do the OP's homework for them, but I want to give them a hint so they can figure out the answer (and, ideally, come back and write and accept an answer—who doesn't love when that happens?).</sub>

Comment: Yes, my comment is a temporary way to give a hint to OP about possible way how that task could be solved. I do agree, that finally it should be deleted. But obviously, that should not happen just now, as OP is still searching for a solution. `doing their job according to those standards` A "job" to delete all comments without a sane reason?  It's nonsense.

Comment: I very frequently find the answers I'm looking for in comments, so this logic is stupid. "But it won't be search indexable!" Okay? But not all comments can or should be answers, so... You want a site that doesn't have answers on it then?

Comment: Goodness, like, do you people actually use StackExchange websites, or are you just here to get off on moderating?

Answer (score 8):

Posting answers as comments is detrimental to the site. It gives the OP the solution without allowing them to accept the answer. It provides an answer without allowing others to determine how valid that answer is (by up/downvoting it). It makes the question appear unanswered, thus making the "unanswered" tab invalid.

An answer-comment like that *should* be deleted.

If you want to answer the question, *answer the question*. If you want to make the site better, **answer the question**. If you want to resolve the issue, ***ANSWER THE QUESTION!***

Whatever the intent is behind posting answers as comments, it's not behavior we want on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unless it's a duplicate, then close as a duplicate :P.

Comment: My comment is just an idea (a hint) how the task could be solved.  It isn't a complete answer (and actually I don't have an answer to post). This comment may help someone else to write real answer, with full code and explanations.  Why do you think that comments containing hints to possible solution should be deleted?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Because, more often than not, such comments *do* give the OP the answer. But since most OP's don't care about posting a proper answer in the answer box, nor do you care about actually providing a proper answer, the question will appear "unanswered". Even though it has been answered. Stack Overflow is not about providing "hints" to users; it's about providing *answers*, creating a searchable database of problems with solutions. Such comments do not help in that endeavor.

Comment: Did my comment give an answer?  Or is it just a hint?  Can you feel the difference between what is an answer and what is not an answer?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: My point is that hints do not lead to answers being posted. They lead to dead questions which appear unanswered but which may or may not in fact have answers. Comments are ultimately supposed to translate into some form of answer, either through the OP improving the question or something else. And if a comment doesn't, then the comment only helps the OP, not the next person with that problem. That's bad.

Comment: "My point is that hints do not lead to answers being posted." **What?** Have you gone insane? Hints don't lead to answers? Really? You haven't thought this through, surely.