# Did my comment just disappear?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I posted a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868070) question about an hour ago, asking for some clarification. When I refreshed the page (habit), after doing other things for a while, I noticed that my comment was not there anymore.

Did it somehow get deleted? I don't think this has happened to me before. I tried checking my profile to see if it was under `All actions/Comments`, but it's not showing up there either.

Bit confused...

Comment: [This answer generally sums it up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370621/833070). Comments are generally considered temporary and can disappear depending on the circumstances.

Comment: It would have needed to have been flagged though or deleted by a passing moderator. Was the comment snarky in any way?

Comment: That's fine, I'm just a bit surprised as I've never seen it happen before.

Comment: @MartinSmith, no it was something along the lines of *"Can you clarify what you mean by focusable divs? Divs aren't focusable"*

Comment: Someone must have flagged it, and a moderator decided to honor the flag and delete it. Only a mod can tell you more. But comments do get deleted very often. And usually is best not to worry about it.

Comment: *Comment removed*

Comment: If it's a productive comment and civil comment and a mod approves a bogus flag on it, it is cause for concern.

Comment: @faintsignal, that's what I thought.

Comment: The comment was flagged as "no longer needed" and deleted by a moderator. My guess is that there was a misreading here and they thought that this comment had been flagged because the discussion had provided the detail requested by the comment, when in fact it hadn't. I've undeleted the comment and pinged the moderator who handled this so that they can provide more color on this. Guessing it was an honest mistake, it can sometimes be hard to judge comments people flag as being obsolete.

Comment: @BradLarson, ah thanks for the info. I did suspect something like that had happened, but I was curious nevertheless. Thanks again.

Comment: @Brad Larson: We all know that comments can be deleted willy-nilly even if they *haven't* yet outlived their usefulness.

Comment: @BradLarson Do the moderators see who made the flag when they handle it? If it's the post owner who flagged as no longer needed, they might have done so because they already read it, and so the comment would no longer be needed, because either they follow it or decide not to, the comment being there no longer helps. However if it were an unrelated 3rd party doing the flagging, then yeah that's kind of weird.

Comment: @DavyM - We do now (this is a relatively recent change), and this flag did come from an unrelated third party. Knowing that the flag came from a post owner may actually cause us to be more skeptical of the flag in certain cases, because many people (including a few longtime members) flag polite comments that are even remotely critical of their posts. In some cases it does help to confirm that edits were incorporated, etc. Not sure why this one was flagged to begin with, I don't see any targeting or other anomalous behavior. Sometimes we just get odd flags.

Comment: I deleted the comment there. When I saw the question, the OP had replied to your comment, and another user had updated the question making changes to that sentence which you had pointed out in the comment. Therefore I assumed that the issue was addressed, and honored the flag. Sorry for that.

Comment: @BhargavRao, while I don't care about my comment being removed, per se, at all, I do think it is a weird practice to remove comments unless they somehow violate the rules or are completely irrelevant. Just my 2c

Comment: Actually comments are thought to be "ephemeral", and are meant to be for clarifications (which you asked rightly), and then deleted once the issue is addressed (which I assumed it was). If we look at it in that way, it does make sense, and doesn't look much weird.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I disagree. Unnecessary removal just adds confusion. If it doesn't need removal, it's always best left alone.

Comment: The use case for the _"no longer needed"_ flag is to remove comments like this, that were made obsolete by the circumstances (e.g. edits in the post addressed or incoporated the comment suggestions). Unncecesary comments are noise, they distract from what's important (the post). In this specific case the comment was removed in error, but Bhargav's reasoning was sound despite misjudging the circumstances.

Comment: @yivi, yes, when the circumstances warrant a "cleaning up". I wouldn't consider 5 comments as noisy or distracting. The flag you are referring to has the hint: *"This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post."* - I don't think it fits this description at all. What you are saying is basically that the flag is there so that we can ping mods to remove comments as soon as they are addressed, rather than using it for what the hint says. If anything, it is only confusing to the author of the comment... I wasn't sure if it was deleted or if I forgot to submit it.

Comment: Yes, that’s what the flag is for. Again, in this case was done in error. But that’s exactly what the flag is for.

Comment: @yivi, are you sure about that? Can you imagine how many flags mods would receive per day on this category alone? Besides, what you are saying doesn't match with the flags description.

Comment: Mods handle **a lot** of these flags. But NLN flags are handled very quickly and en masse.

Comment: @yivi, okay, you seem to know, so I'll take that for granted. I guess the hint needs updating though.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: This is exactly what I meant by my reply to Brad. Anyone can just deem a comment no longer needed even if it *isn't yet*, but because cOmMeNtS aRe ePhEmErAl no one may dispute their deletion regardless of whether or not the assessment of the comment as no longer needed was correct and the deletion actually warranted. It *does not* make sense from the perspective of your comment because *the assessment of the comment was wrong in the first place*. And it's absolutely not usual for a request for clarification to be deleted *before* clarification has been provided.

Comment: @BoltClock, I couldn't care less about comments being removed. The problem is that it happens silently. It's not a great UX when your stuff just vanishes without trace. What "makes sense" doesn't always align with a good user experience.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I'm aware of that. There have been proposals to improve the UX by notifying users that their comments were deleted, etc, but the response hasn't been favorable.

Comment: @BoltClock, honestly, change proposals around here are almost never popular. At least in my experience.

Answer (score -24):

Yes, Stack Overflow likes to censor comments.

Comment: If you *really* think so, then, where's your proof?

Comment: Deleted comments aren't saved under `/users/[id]/[name]?tab=activity&sort=comments`.

Comment: Why would they be? They're _deleted_!

Comment: @jhpratt Exactly! And, you can see recently deleted questions at `https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<user-id>`. Substitute `recently-deleted-answers` to view answers.

Comment: it can be hard to differenciate Censorship from mod deletion of a comment according to CoC. But it's not. Take a look at other exchange site, where if the comment look like a partial answer it will be deleted in a flash especialy on hot question. Remember our old rules: "see no evil". The only censor ship I saw was by Community on "take a sand" post.

Comment: CoC and mod comment suppression is a vast subject where we have no data as the comment are deleted. We can only assume it's ok.

Comment: I checked my SO pokedex and if I noted correctly you use comment as a "Poppet valve" pressure build up and comment are here to realese it. That's not censor ship.. That's moderation. even if So is tilting sometimes..

Comment: Moderators do delete comments, and those deleted comments are not visible to general users, but there is an audit record associated with those deletions that is visible to other moderators and staff. As you can see in my comments above, I was able to see what had happened and undelete the comment when we saw it was still of value. Stack Overflow is run by a private company, and does set ground rules that allow for comments to be deleted at any time by moderators, staff, or even normal community members in certain circumstances.

Comment: This is pure censorship. Mods can't possible know the intricacies of every programming language to be able to decide which comment is useful or not. Let's see how long this comment stays on...